# Stuck with Only a Candle to my Name

Tags: kings-quest

I'm in search of an eye. I decided to use my last coin to obtain the candle, which I successfully got and dyed purple. However, every time I enter the cave and use the candle, Acorn throws me out.

All I have in my inventory are the candle and a bell.

Regarding other items I had:

> I gave the fruit and mushrooms to the baker (although without a coin to trade, I can't get the pie). Amaya the blacksmith likes my candle, and says it would help her in her quest to chase away the wolves, but it sure doesn't do anything for me.

What am I missing?

Comment: There's no need to spoiler tag important parts of the question. The general rule of thumb is: Does the question make any sense without the part I want to put in a spoiler tag?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the purple candle itself

> Can be passed off for an eye of the Snarling Snarlax!